# Let $E$ be a Banach space, $x \in E$, and $f \in E^\star$. What does $\langle f, x\rangle$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

I'm reading Part 3.2 of textbook *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*:

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $f \in E^{\star}$. We denote by $\varphi_{f}: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the linear functional $\varphi_{f}(x)=\langle f, x\rangle$. As $f$ runs through $E^{\star}$ we obtain a collection $\left(\varphi_{f}\right)_{f \in E^{\star}}$ of maps from $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$. We now ignore the usual topology on $E$ (associated to $\| \cdot \|$ ) and define a new topology on the set $E$ as follows:
>
> **Definition.** The weak topology $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$ on $E$ is the coarsest topology associated to the collection $\left(\varphi_{f}\right)_{f \in E^{\star}}$ (in the sense of Section $3.1$ with $X=E, Y_{i}=\mathbb{R}$, for each $i$, and $I=E^{\star}$ ).
>
> Note that every map $\varphi_{f}$ is continuous for the usual topology and therefore $t h e$ weak topology is weaker than the usual topology.

Could you explain what $\langle f, x\rangle$ means? My naïve guess is that $\langle f, x\rangle := f(x)$. If so, $\varphi_f = f$ itself. Is there any motivation to use the inner product symbol and $\varphi_f$ rather than $f$ itself?

Comment: $\left<f,x\right>:=f(x)$ and is called the [natural pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Algebraic_dual_space).

Comment: It is just the value of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: Using $\varphi_f$ instead of $f$ is strange to me, but $\langle f,x\rangle$ for $f(x)$ is pretty standard.

Comment: I think that the notation with the inner product arises from representation of linear functionals. The most regular case is the context of Hilbert spaces where any linear functional can be expressed as a inner product with a fixed vector.